# Building Docker images using Jenkins results in "Unsupported protocol scheme found"

Tags: jenkins, docker

I'm following [this](https://www.katacoda.com/courses/jenkins/build-docker-images) online tutorial line by line. But at step 3 - **Task: Configure Plugin** - I'm getting this error message, when I press "Test connection" button:

> Unsupported protocol scheme found: http://172.17.0.59:2345

Here is a screen of what I've done:

[image]

So, what is wrong with that and what is the right way of configuring Docker image with Jenkins?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I followed the same tutorial, and entered instead:

```
 tcp://172.17.0.18:2345/
```

The test did work:

```
Version = 1.10.0, API Version = 1.22
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: It is great! Thank you so much!

Comment: after I had enabled docker remote API and tested it with curl ... i was trying tcp://localhost:4243 and tcp://127.0.0.1:4243 but these failed ... i had to use tcp://mydomain.com:4243 to get it to work

Comment: How to find my docker remote API url in my machine ?

Comment: @vijay It depends on which docker for which machine. for instance, a docker managed with docker-machine would give you its url with `docker-machine ip`