# Getting Unsupported protocol scheme error with docker in pycharm

Tags: docker, pycharm, docker-machine

I'm getting the following error when launching docker interpreter in pycharm

Error:com.github.dockerjava.api.exception.DockerClientException: Unsupported protocol scheme found: ''. Only 'tcp://' or 'unix://' supported.

I've tried to ssh into the image that i'm running and check it manually, and everything looks to be working fine.
The Ip address of the machine is alright as well.

```
NAME            ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL                         SWARM   DOCKER    ERRORS
MyVM   -        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.100:2376           v1.11.2
```

Comment: Can you try using `tcp://` in pyCharm docker settings like in  [Building Docker images using Jenkins results in "Unsupported protocol scheme found"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40522474/building-docker-images-using-jenkins-results-in-unsupported-protocol-scheme-fou)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I raised a bug for this on jetbrains when i saw this was a bug on their side.

I resolved this by removing all the remote interpreters and adding anew

Answer (score 5):

Happened to me after upgrading to PyCharm 2017.1.2

I've resolved this by configuring the Python Interpreter - click "New..." near the Server pulldown menu. This will open a new dialog in which the Certificate Folder  text field has the value "~/.docker" - empty this value and click ok.
(see also https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2017.1/docker-2.html which states that this item is deprecated and should be empty)

Answer (score 4):

If you go into Preferences >> Build, Execution, Deployment >> Docker and look at your interpreter, it seems the "API URL" field was wiped out during an upgrade (at least for me). If you fix that field (make a new interpreter and just copy in the value), things work again.

Answer (score 1):

On a macos with Intellij, had the same error:

> Error:com.github.dockerjava.api.exception.DockerClientException: Unsupported protocol scheme found: ''. Only 'tcp://' or 'unix://' supported.

Solved it by:

```
1. Going View -> Tools -> Docker
2. right click on 'Docker' (for me, bottom menu, left side)
3. click 'Edit configuration'
4. change from 'TCP socket' to 'Docker for Mac'
5. Click Connect (the play button on the left in the same Docker menu)
```

You should now be connected and see your images and containers.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, but I find a way to solve it.
Go to Jenkins dir and `grep http://localhost:4243/`

On my case, one file have this parameter:

```
org.jenkinsci.plugins.dockerbuildstep.DockerBuilder.xml
```

I changed directly in this file from `http://localhost:4243/` to `tcp://localhost:4243`. Restart Jenkins service and  the problem disappeared